# Boost linking error - single undefined reference

Tags: c++, boost, linker

I'm having an odd linking problem with Boost (version 1.58). I'm building with g++ 4.8 on Ubuntu 15.10.

I get the following error:

> undefined reference to
>   'boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string
>   const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)' collect2: error: ld returned 1
>   exit status

What's strange is that all other symbols from lboost_program_options are found; options_description is the only undefined reference. If I comment out uses of options_description but keep uses of positional_options_description (which I'm also using) then the whole program compiles and links flawlessly.  I am linking with -lboost_program_options, and if I remove this then as expected there are 8 missing boost::options_description symbols.

For a long time linking has worked correctly. Without any build system changes that I'm aware of it suddenly broke. The only systems level change was an upgrade to Ubuntu 15.10, which I don't think should have affected anything.

Any thoughts or suggestions appreciated.

**Update:** After lots of fiddling I got this working again, although I'm not sure what did it. I'm still interested in any answers to what could cause this type of behavior though.

Comment: Upgrading your OS would almost definitely upgrade many packages. It's likely that you installed boost(-dev) using apt-get and that it is now at a newer version.

Comment: That's possible, but I don't see why it would cause this error. I checked to make sure that the API and packaging was the same in the current version of boost.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the ABI is compatible (you're using the same compiler version and flags used when compiling the boost libraries).

On Ubuntu, this means using stock GCC with libstdc++.

If you can't, compile your own Boost System and Boost Program Options binaries using your preferred flags.

Similar things prevent code samples from linking on http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com if your compiler is not the same as used when compiling boost there.

Comment: Could you explain the answer a bit further? I have the same problem and your answer seem to be what I need. I tried so many solution online but none worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after upgrading to Ubuntu 15.10 with a different symbol missing in a lib belonging to `boost::program_options`.

It helped to simply clean up the whole project by throwing away all object files etc. and recompiling it from scratch.

Comment: Interesting to hear that this affected other people too. I definitely tried "make clean" right away.

Comment: To be more exact, I have implemented an interface lib between my app and `boost::program_options`, which I link statically to my app. I needed to clean the lib project as well to make it work. To be sure I did that manually.